# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempts to change the schema (add/remove fields) occurred in jacoco

Tags: java, jacoco

When I use  `agent` with jacoco, if the agent's startup mode is premain, jacoco can run normally, but if it is agentmain, jacoco cannot run normally. This seems to be caused by the JVM's protection mechanism for classes, and nothing else. How can I bypass this check?

```
   @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
                            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) {
        try {
            if (className == null) {
                return null;
            }

            String urlPath = scanPath.replace(".", "/");
            if (!className.startsWith(urlPath)) {
                return null;
            }

            if (className.contains("$")) {
                return null;
            }
            if (className.equals(CoverageTransformer.class.getName())) {
                return null;
            }
            return new Instrumenter().instrument(classfileBuffer,className);
           
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("coverageTransformer fail,error={}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)
```

Comment: This is not a protection mechanism. This is a missing feature. There is no way to bypass the lack of a feature.